# BottomSheetDialogFragment enter from within Fragment's view (Above BottomTabLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to show a BottomSheetDialogFragment, but have it appear within the content view of my fragment. The reason for this is that I have a Bottom TabLayout, and there are cases when I want to show the Dialog, but not cover the tabs. For this to work, I imagine the dialog entering from the view of the Fragment, as opposed to the view of the Activity.  Any advice?

Comment: You can't do that because `BottomSheetDialogFragment` purpose is to be modal, which means it will always be above your views. You might want to move from modal to persistent bottom sheet, that has lower elevation than your tab layout. FYI this is against material design guidelines specs, if you are following them.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much (I was actually just following your sample app in github)  Any chance that you could point me to the general section where this goes against Material Design?

Comment: BottomSheetDialogFragment will always show above all your views and your views will not be focusable/clickable, that is the "against" in a nutshell. Head to bottom sheet component section of the MD guidelines.

Comment: Just because it's not material design doesn't mean you shouldn't do it, there are many cases where following material design will ruin your app